# Recursion, find the formula for the general term $a_n = a_{n-1}+20 a_{n-2} ; \ a_0 := 1; \ \ a_1 := 1;$ (not solvable system)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

**$$a_n = a_{n-1}+20 a_{n-2} ; \ a_0 := 1; \  \ a_1 := 1;$$**
I did these steps:

1. I found the associated equation: $x^2 -x -20$
2. The two solutions are $\lambda_1= 5 \ \lambda_2= -4$
3. I substitute these values to : $a_n=B_1 \lambda_1^n + B_2 \lambda_2^n$ to obtain $a_n=B_1 \cdot 5^n + B_2 \cdot (-4)^n$
4. Now I setup the system: $$\begin{equation}
       \begin{cases}
         1= B_1 \cdot 5^1 + B_2 \cdot (-4)^1\\
         1= B_1 \cdot 5^1 + B_2 \cdot (-4)^1
       \end{cases}\,.
   \end{equation}$$
5. seems that the system is not solvable for all variables.

And now? what to do? how can I find the formula for the general term?

Comment: Please correct your typo: you have $a_0=1$ and $a_0=1$.

Comment: The exponent in the first equation is zero

Comment: @TonyK sorry! now is correct

Comment: @lhf you're right! I'll try to solve in this way thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point 4. should be

\begin{align}
B_15^0+B_2(-4)^0&=1\\
B_15^1+B_2(-4)^1&=1
\end{align}

\begin{align}
B_1+B_2&=1\\
5B_1-4B_2&=1
\end{align}

from which you get $B_1=\frac{5}{9},~B_2=\frac{4}{9}$. And this is really a solution as one can check.